# Add Next Prev button this thumbnail gallery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Please help me to enable "Next", "Prev" Button work along with the thumbnail please. Thumbnail clicks works fine. I want to make navigation arrows work along with the thumbnail. Thanks guys!

You can see the way it works below, Just need to enable arrows for navigation as the way it is now.

I would not want to change the current div structure as this template has been implemented already,

```js
  // Product image gallery
    $(".thumbLink").click(function(event) {        
        var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".thumbLink").removeClass('active');
        $( this ).addClass( "active" );
        $('.main-pimage').hide();
        $('.main-pimage').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.main-pimage').html('<img src="' + image + '" class="custom img-fluid"/>');
        return false;
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <!-- Product Gallery      -->
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <aside class="pgallery">     
            <div class="row">
              <!-- Thumbs -->
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="thumbnails d-flex flex-row flex-lg-column h-100">
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=AA" class="thumbLink active"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=A" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=BB" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=B" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=CC" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=C" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=DD" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=D" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=EE" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=E" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=FF" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=F" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>                  
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Thumbs -->

              <!-- Main image -->
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="zoom main-pimage" id="izoomy">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=AA" alt="" class="custom img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="slidy">
                  <a id="prev">Prev</a>
                  <a id="next">Next</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Main image -->
            </div>

          </aside>
        </div>
        <!-- Product Gallery ends -->
</div>
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried to get prev/next working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to find the next/prev thumbnails...

```
$("#next").click(function(event) {        
    $(".thumbLink.active").parent().next().find(".thumbLink").trigger('click');
});

$("#prev").click(function(event) {        
    $(".thumbLink.active").parent().prev().find(".thumbLink").trigger('click');
});
```

[Working Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/5GeVbVQA38)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this and would appreciate this. Just wondering can this be like a loop when on the last image click and start from the first one again and when on the first image click prev to start from last one.

Answer (score 0):

Try below example

```js
$(".thumbLink").click(function(event) {        
         var image = $(this).attr("rel");
        $(".thumbLink").removeClass('active');
        $( this ).addClass( "active" );
        $('.main-pimage').hide();
        $('.main-pimage').fadeIn('slow');
        $('.main-pimage').html('<img src="' + image + '" class="custom img-fluid"/>');

        return false;
    });

 $("#next").click(function() {
 $('.thumbLink.active').parent('.tsack').next('div').find($('.thumbLink')).trigger('click')
});

$("#prev").click(function() {
  $('.thumbLink.active').parent('.tsack').prev('div').find($('.thumbLink')).trigger('click')
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
        <!-- Product Gallery      -->
        <div class="col-md-5">
          <aside class="pgallery">     
            <div class="row">
              <!-- Thumbs -->
              <div class="col-lg-2">
                <div class="thumbnails d-flex flex-row flex-lg-column h-100">
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=AA" class="thumbLink active"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=A" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=BB" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=B" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=CC" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=C" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=DD" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=D" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=EE" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=E" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="pt-wrap mr-2 mr-lg-0 mb-2 tsack">
                    <a href="#" rel="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=FF" class="thumbLink"><img width="" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=F" alt="" class="pthumb img-fluid"></a>
                  </div>                  
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Thumbs -->

              <!-- Main image -->
              <div class="col-lg-10">
                <div class="zoom main-pimage" id="izoomy">
                    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x300?text=AA" alt="" class="custom img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="slidy">
                  <a id="prev">Prev</a>
                  <a id="next">Next</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Main image -->
            </div>

          </aside>
        </div>
        <!-- Product Gallery ends -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks PPL and really grateful for your answer.